# Is it possible to view the models formed by Bagging Classifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is it possible to see the individual base classifiers that are formed by `BaggingClassifier()`? The code I am working with is the example code from the sklearn library for making a prediction via bagging:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=100, n_features=4,
                       n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
                       random_state=0, shuffle=False)
clf = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=SVC(),
                    n_estimators=10, random_state=0).fit(X, y)
clf.predict([[0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

The code correctly returns the prediction, but I need to see the models that were actually formed by `BaggingClassifier`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are available in the `estimators_` attribute.  See [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.html).

Comment: Thanks, and to add more context to anyone else that needs the data, the raw data itself for each model is in the estimators_samples_ attribute.